# Ansible - Multiple Dictionary Files

Tags: ansible

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: switch
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: GET DATA
    include_vars: ./host_vars/file.yml

  - name: GENERATE CONFIG
    template:
      src: ./templates/accessvlan.j2
      dest: ./output/{{ item.switch }}.conf
    with_items: 
    - '{{ab351E}}'
    - '{{ab361E}}'
```

Variable file: `./host_vars/file.yml`

```
---
ab351E:
- { switch: ab35-1E, port: Gi1/14, vlan: 1310 }
- { switch: ab35-1E, port: Gi1/29, vlan: 1382 }
- { switch: ab35-1E, port: Gi1/15, vlan: 1310 }

ab361E:
- { switch: ab36-1E, port: Gi1/15, vlan: 1410 }
- { switch: ab36-1E, port: Gi1/26, vlan: 1482 }
- { switch: ab36-1E, port: Gi1/17, vlan: 1410 }
```

Jinja2 template: /templates/accessvlan.j2

```
conf t
{% for host in ab351E %}
int {{ host.port }}
switchport access vlan {{ host.vlan }}
{% endfor %}
end
copy run start
```

I can make the above playbook work without issues. However, as seen in the Jinja2 template, I can use only one dictionary variable (ab351E) from the `with_item`.

How do I edit my Jinja2 template such that I can utilize both the dictionary variables (ab351E & ab361E) referred to in the playbook under `with_item`?

My goal is to generate 2 configuration files: ab35-1E.conf & ab36-1E.conf.

**ab35-1E.conf** file would look like this:

```
conf t
int G1/14
switchport access vlan 1310
int G1/29
switchport access vlan 1382
int G1/15
switchport access vlan 1310
end
copy run start
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pass item to the template using an `include` to get the behavior that you would like:

```
conf t
{% for host in item %}
int {{ host.port }}
switchport access vlan {{ host.vlan }}
{% endfor %}
end
copy run start
```

And

Move this block to a file called 'generate_config.yml'

```
- name: GENERATE CONFIG
  template:
    src: ./templates/accessvlan.j2
    dest: ./output/{{ item.switch }}.conf
```

And in your playbook:

```
- name: generate all configs
  include: generate_config.yml
  with_items:
  . . .
```